# Kotlin compilation error: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors, metadata

> Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin.
> The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16.

How can I resolve this problem????

Comment: whats your kotlin version in gradle files?